# cakephp hosting "Cake is NOT able to connect to the database."

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, shared-hosting

beginner level stuff-
-i recently hosted my cakephp project on 000webhost.com 
-it shows the cake homepage
-but at the same time shows

Cake is NOT able to connect to the database.

Datasource class a2952772 could not be found.

-i have tried editing root/app/config/database.php number of times.
-i have created mysql database on 000webhost.com

i guess there is some problem with
$datasource in

```
public $default = array(
        'datasource' => '????',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'mysql11.000webhost.com',
        'login' => '*****',
        'password' => '*****',
        'database' => 'db1',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
```

if anybody has hosted and configured databases on 000webhost.com ,plz help...

Comment: You did not created a database, if you created then you might not created user. If you created the user, then provide the proper credential in `login` and `password` config array.

Comment: and if you did both of those you still need to create the permissions for the user to access the database.

Comment: Also provide the Database server IP, instead of the string based host name in the `host` section.

Comment: I have hostname,login,password etc sorted out. I just need to know where is datasource on a shared server??e.g. datasouce=/home/username........

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a valid datasource, such as `'Database/Mysql'`. Also check the [CakePHP database configuration section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#cake-database-configuration).

Comment: my app is working perfectly at localhost. The problem is at the host i.e. 000webhost.com  where i don't know what shold be the value of $database i have tried /home,/home/username,/username so on.......

Comment: The error message indicates that the `Datasource class` cannot be found, and that the class name it's looking for is `a2952772`. To me this indicates that you've probably mixed up datasource and database.

Comment: suppose my database name id db1. Then what should be values of datasource and database on a shared host like 0000webhost.com?? i guess 'database'='db1' datasource=?

Comment: Since 000webhost.com uses a MySQL database server, the correct value for datasource should be `Database/Mysql`.